# Microsoft Open XML SDK 2.5 - can I rely on undocumented public methods?

Tags: c#, openxml, office-interop, openxml-sdk

Via Intellisense, I've found that the DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.WordprocessingDocument class exposes public methods ToFlatOpcString()/ToFlatOpcDocument(), which (as the name suggests) converts the OpenXml document to a string/XDocument in Flat OPC format.

The [API documents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.packaging.wordprocessingdocument_members.aspx), however, make no reference to these methods - does this mean they are at risk of being removed by Microsoft in a later update? Is it safe to rely on these undocumented public methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers to your questions:

> 1. Does this mean they are at risk of being removed by Microsoft in a later update?

No api documentation does not imply they are more at risk of being removed by Microsoft than methods that have documentation.

> 2. Is it safe to rely on these undocumented public methods

Absolutely.

**More info:**

In 2014, Microsoft [made the announcement](https://blogs.office.com/en-us/2014/06/25/open-xml-sdk-goes-open-source/) that the OpenXml library is to follow the [open source model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-source_model).  You can download all of the code and review these methods via the [OpenXml GitHub site](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK).  You can even fork the code and work off of your new repository to safeguard against the case where Microsoft did decide to deprecate methods.

A [quick search](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=ToFlatOpcDocument&type=) shows the method has documentation in the GitHub repo.